# Find $\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{x^{23}-1}{x^{2.3}-1}$

Tags: limits

I've asked 3 Math instructors from our Uni to help me solve this limit problem and it remains unsolved. It's from an old exam from an introductory level course, so it should be easily solvable:

$$\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{x^{23}-1}{x^{2.3}-1}$$
([View in WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit+as+x+approaches+1&rawformassumption=%7B%22F%22,+%22Limit%22,+%22limitfunction%22%7D+-%3E%22(x%5E23-1)%2F(x%5E(2.3)-1)%22&rawformassumption=%7B%22FP%22,+%22Limit%22,+%22direction%22%7D+-%3E+%22Left%22&rawformassumption=%7B%22FVarOpt%22%7D+-%3E+%7B%7B%22Limit%22,+%22limitvariable2%22%7D,+%7B%22Limit%22,+%22limit2%22%7D,+%7B%22Limit%22,+%22direction2%22%7D,+%7B%22Limit%22,+%22direction%22%7D,+%7B%22Limit%22,+%22limitvariable%22%7D%7D))

Edit: Please allow me to comment on the accusations thrown at me by multiple people in the comments.

First, I was accused of posting a homework question. As I said, this is an old exam question. For proof, here is a picture of the exam:

[image: Exam picture]

It's in Finnish, but you can see that the date is 2015 and the same problem is in 1b.

Second, I was accused of not putting in any effort to solve this before asking the question. For proof of effort, here are my scribbles from last week:

[image: Scribbles]

I did not originally post these because I felt they do not contribute anything to the discussion. They are just scribbles with poor notation and many mistakes.

Thirdly, I was laughed at for being so bad at Math that I can't even solve this simple problem. This is absolutely true, I was unable to solve this problem. That's why I posted a question here asking if anybody could help me solve it. If I had been able to solve it by myself, I would not have posted the question.

Some commenters also wondered how I have any reputation at all, since I'm so bad at Math. I didn't make any claims about being good at Math; in fact I said in OP that this should be easily solvable (even though I was unable to solve it). I realize that Math is one of my weakest areas and that's precisely why I've put a lot of effort to it for the past few months (as can be seen from my post history).

Also, I said that 3 instructors at our University were unable to solve this. Someone misquoted me on purpose as saying "*professors*" were unable to solve this. This would be prepostrous and I never said that. Instructors are simply students who get paid by the University to help other students. They are great help, but they don't know everything. I obviously can't prove what these instructors can or can't solve, but since I proved the other accusations as false, perhaps you can just take my word for it with this one.

Comment: I suppose the `,3` goes into the exponent?

Comment: Have you tried to solve it yourself? If so, what have you tried? Where did you get stuck? (And while you're at it, you should really replace the title with something actually descriptive.)

Comment: The limit is $$10$$ Now, your turn: how would you attack this question?

Comment: I find it implausible that three university students of mathematics, presumably sufficiently qualified to teach or assist other students in mathematics, would be unable to solve such a trivial limit; indeed, the question is so trivial the answer came to my mind before I could even type this comment.

Comment: Yes, that is indeed a mysterious repotato. But maybe not assume everyone votes on the same criteria that you do.

Comment: Atte, if you posted the same question and ***typeset it properly yourself,*** meanwhile avoided histrionics, people would not be making wild guesses about the background of the question.

Comment: @AtteJuvonen You should share your downvotes to your 3 maths instructors :-)

Comment: @AtteJuvonen Since you have edited properly and answered our questions; I have removed my downvote. It would have been far better if you had done it earlier, before getting 10 massive downvotes (excluded mine)By the way -  '***Better late than never***'

Comment: (+1) for trying hard to make a nice question out of the mess in beginning...btw. some of the comments are really unprofessional

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set $y=x^{2,3}, y^{10}=x^{23}$ and proceed with the L'Hospital Rule as normal.

Comment: Just wondering why you used L'Hopital after the substitution. After the substitution, you obtain: $$\lim_{y \to 1} \frac{y^{10}-1}{y-1}$$ Notice that by definition, this is equivalent to evaluating $(y^{10})'$ at $y=1$.

Comment: @projectilemotion: I'm more used to the definition of derivative with h->0, thus I couldn't see it. Nice observation though ;)

Answer (score 2):

This limit satisfies the conditions to directly apply [L'Hopital's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule).
$$\lim_{x\to 1} \frac{x^{23}-1}{x^{2.3}-1}=\lim_{x\to 1} \frac{\frac{d}{dx}(x^{23}-1)}{\frac{d}{dx}(x^{2.3}-1)}=\cdots$$
Can you continue?

Answer (score 1):

This is a basic result from high-school:
$$\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{x^\alpha-1}{x-1}=\alpha$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\text{Substitute } t=x-1 :\hspace{1cm} \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{(t+1)^\alpha-1}{t}$$

Now Taylor expand $f(t) = (t+1)^\alpha$ around $t=0$ up to $O(t^2)$ and you get the answer.

If we don't want to Taylor it, then we can use the famouse binomial theorem for integers:

$$(t+1)^\alpha = 1+\alpha t+\cdots$$

And the dots will contain more $t$s than we need, since only one $t$ gets eaten ( wait what, you eat $t$ ? )

Comment: You are humorous, :-)